# Integrated Intel graphics seem to cause random crashes

Tags: 18.04, kernel, intel-graphics, crash, hda-intel

After plenty of digging around the forms and some trial and error, it seems that when I allow the kernel drivers for my integrated video card to load(the motherboard is a MSI Z170-A Pro with Intel Z170 Express Chipset - `lshw -c` display reports the `HD Graphics 530` and currently unclaimed), my system becomes randomly unstable and will hang/crash/become unresponsive after finishing a boot.

To place a band aid on my solution, I've modified GRUB to be `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nomodeset acpi=force"` as to disable the kernel video drivers, which by default, reverts Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (recently upgraded from 16 LTS with `4.4.0-21-generic` which worked and didn't suffer these problems if I didn't upgrade the kernel) to use `llvmpipe` (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits) for the graphics driver.

While this band aid is a solution, is there a way to have stability and my Intel graphics at the same time? I was looking last night at the idea of installing and loading the Intel graphics in the OS instead of at the kernel, however, this doesn't seem to be the new norm with 18.04/17.10.

Comment: Not an answer but there are some additional kernel parameters you can research. This is from my grub: `"noplymouth fastboot acpiphp.disable=1 pcie_aspm=force scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 vt.handoff=7 i915.enable_guc_loading=1 i915.enable_guc_submission=1 i915.edp_vswing=2 nopti nospectre_v2 nospec"`